# How can i run Scene and App on swiftUI using ipad Playground for swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

i use Apple ipad pro M1 for codding a Swift and SwiftUI, but now i stop here because i do not now what i should do to this error

the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct Welcoming:App {
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        TabView {
            Text("one")
            Text("tow")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the error:

> No exact matches call 'setLiveView' instance method

[This image for the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G08Ce.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setLiveView` takes a SwiftUI `View` as a parameter. You are trying to send it `Welcoming` which is defined as an `App`. Instead, encapsulate your view into a `View` you can send to the `PlaygroundPage`:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("one")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("One")
                }
            Text("two")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Two")
                }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```